# SQLAlchemy bulk insert from JSON data

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My first try with an ORM, trying to understand how it works, but having a bit of a challenge:

What I'm trying to do is, fit a JSON from an API into a SQLAlchemy model, and then bulk insert all entries into my database. But for some reason I'm getting an error in SQLAlchemy.

From what I understand of the error, at some point in time, when assigning the data to my model, it's being converted into a dict, when I thought it should be a list of `class objects`.

My expected result is a successful insert of all the entries. Can anybody help figuring what I might be doing wrong?

Appreciate.*

**The error**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 
Failed processing pyformat-parameters;
Python 'dict' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

**The JSON:**

```
{
"all_orders": [
    {
    "id": 456215587,
    "created_at": "2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00",
    "order_number": null,
    },
    {
    "id": null,
    "created_at": "2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00",
    "order_number": 1982,
    }]
}
```

**The Function**

```
def update_orders(all_orders):

    cursor = db_cursor()
    session = db_session()
    orders_entries = []

    for orders in all_orders:

       order_id        = orders.get("id", {})
       order_number    = orders.get("order_number", {})
       created_at      = orders.get("created_at", {})

       new_entry = SalesOrders(order_id=order_id,
                               order_number=order_number,
                               created_at=created_at)

       orders_entries.append(new_entry)

    session.add_all(orders_entries)
    session.commit()
```

**The Model**

```
class SalesOrders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_orders'

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, index=True)
    order_id = Column(String(50), primary_key=True, server_default=text("''"))
    order_number = Column(String(50))
    created_at = Column(String(100))
```

EDIT to make it verifiable.
The function .get() is was creating a dictionary, instead of a `None` object, and SQLAlchemy wasn't able to insert a Python Dictionary.

Comment: "PS: Nevermind field names, I edited the code to make it smaller." is no excuse for not providing a [mcve], stressing **verifiable**. The code and the data you've presented contains multiple errors, but not the one that you are asking about.

Comment: You're right. I'll try to make it verifiable without pasting tons of code.

Comment: @IljaEverilä edited it to make it verifiable and ended up finding out the problem. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the `get()` function, SQLAlchemy is getting a dict, which is not expected in an SQL Insert function, which is producing the error.
To make it work, just pass the `None` object instead of the `{}`.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import *


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'main.db')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


data = {
   "all_orders": [
      {
         "id": 456213548,
         "created_at": "2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00",
         "number": null
      },
      {
         "id":4562222222,
         "created_at": "2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00",
         "number": 1982,
      }
   ]
}


class SalesOrders(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sales_orders'

    order_id = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True, server_default='')
    order_number = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created_at = db.Column(db.String(50))


def update_orders(data):
    orders_entries = []
    for orders in data["all_orders"]:
        new_entry = SalesOrders(order_id=orders['id'],
                                order_number=orders['number'])
        orders_entries.append(new_entry)
    db.session.add_all(orders_entries)
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Example:

```
>>> import app
>>> from app import *
>>> data
{'all_orders': [{'id': 456213548, 'created_at': '2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00', 'number': 1982}, {'id': 4562222222, 'created_at': '2018-11-04T23:18:18-02:00', 'number': 1982}]}
>>> update_orders(data)
>>> SalesOrders.query.all()
[<SalesOrders 456213548>, <SalesOrders 4562222222>]
```

Comment: Thanks. As a user pointed out above, the question was not properly verifiable, as the ID's were indeed unique. What happened was that I was using the `get()` function with `{}` as the parameter, so SQLAlchemy was understanding the input as Python Dict. If you could just adjust your answer to record the "real" problem", I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: The difference between `order_id=orders['id']` and `order_id=orders.get('id', default='some_value')` is the first method raises a `KeyError` if `id` key is not found, while for the second it defaults to `some_value`. In your case it defaults to an empty dictionary `{}`.

Comment: thanks, that's it. it took me a long time to realize due to lack of knowledge on the `get()` function.